# No query results for model [App\Subreddit] when adding moderators to a forum category

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to assign users as moderators to a forum category. At the moment, I am only trying to display route where a user can add moderators `subreddit/{id}/moderators` and display the subreddit name.

For that, I am getting `No query results for model [App\Subreddit]`

I must've messed up the relations between the tables somewhere.

My tables

```
#users: id, name, email...
#subreddits: id, name, user_id...
#moderators: id, user_id, subreddit_id
```

Routes.php

```
Route::get('subreddit/{id}/moderators', [
    'as' => 'moderators',
    'uses' => 'ModeratorsController@create'
]);
```

`Moderator.php` Model

```
class Moderator extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'moderators';

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'subreddit_id'];

    public function subreddit() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subreddit');
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

In `User` Model, I have a `hasManyThrough`

```
public function moderators() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Moderator', 'App\Subreddit');
}
```

In `Subreddit` Model

```
public function moderators() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Moderator');
}
```

And then in `ModeratorsController` I have the following `create()` method

```
public function create(Moderator $moderator, Subreddit $subreddit, User $user)
{
    $subreddit = Subreddit::with('user')->findOrFail($subreddit->id);

    return view('user/moderators')->with('subreddit', $subreddit)->with('user', $user)->with('moderator', $moderator);
}
```

If I change `findOrFail` to `firstOrFail` it will get me the first subreddit in the database, but I don't want the first, I want the exact one I'm trying to add moderators to.

Comment: Please post your tables. What you're doing on the model is surely wrong, because if the moderator belongsTo user, the hasManyThrough relation in the User model is wrong.

Comment: First of all I think that you have a redundancy in your tables. It's sort of a bad practice. why do you keep the user_id in the moderator table while you can access it through subreddit? Or I might misunderstood what you're about to do. please explain a bit more anyway :)

Comment: The `subreddits` table only holds the creator of the category `user_id` while the `moderators` table allows for multiple users to be added as moderators. I am trying to create a view here to allow the owner of the subreddit to add moderators.

Comment: Is moderators table kind of a pivot? I mean does it describe a many-to-many relation between users and subreddits?

Comment: @Mithredate Yes it's a pivot table for users and subreddits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User extends Model{
    public function canModerate(){ //name this as you wish
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subreddit','moderators');
    }
    public function subreddits(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Subreddit');
    }
}

class Subreddit extends Model{
    public function moderators(){ // name this as you wish
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','moderators');
    }

    public function creator(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

remove `id` from `moderators` table and you wont need the `Moderator` class.
Additional documentation can be found [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#many-to-many).

Edit `RouteServiceProvider::boot` method and add the following line:

```
$router->model('subreddit', 'App\Subreddit');
```

Documentation can be found [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-model-binding).

Your route should then look like:

```
Route::resource('subreddit.moderator','ModeratorsController');
```

The URL should look like `http://localhost/subreddit/{subreddit}/moderator/create`

And finally the controller method should be:

```
public function create(Subreddit $subreddit)
{
    $user = $subreddit->creator;
    $moderators = $subreddit->moderators()->get();
    return view('user/moderators')->with(compact('subreddit','user','moderators'));
}
```

Comment: I am still not being able to retreive the `$subreddit->name` of the category that I wanna add moderators to, same error as before. And I don't understand the `creator()` function, I've never used anything like it in my code.

Comment: About the creator() function it's just a naming to describe the relation between Subbreddit model and the User who created it.

Comment: @Mitherdate I already had that in `RouteServiceProvider` and I added one for `App\Moderator` too. Your code is meant for me to retrieve the list of moderators of a given subreddit, yes. But all I'm trying to do at the moment is display the name of the subreddit on the moderators route. And the problem persists.

Comment: try dd($subreddit); in create() method in your controller and see what's the output.

Comment: @Mitherdate I've been trying that for a while, keeps returning empty array or the error I described above `No query results for model [App\Subreddit]`

Comment: Are you passing the correct subreddit id as route param?

Comment: @Mitherdate yes I am sure. I am testing it on a subreddit that I have created so permissions are ok. For example, if I try this inside `create()` method `$subName = Subreddit::with('user')->where('id', '=', $subreddit->id)->get();` I get an empty array.

Comment: Remove the route model binding and dump the id in create method. see if that works :\

Comment: I hope this one works, cause if it doesn't I really don't have any more ideas. try `Route::resource('subreddit.moderator','ModeratorsController');` then add `/create` to your url. for example `http://localhost/subreddit/2/moderator/create` and see if it helps.

Comment: @Mitherdate dudes yes! that was it! Thank you, but can you explain what was wrong and how it was fixed? And please add your last answer to your original post so I can select it as the answer.

Comment: Well there should have been a problem with passing the route param to your controller method so I chose the most obvious way to do it which was  through a RESTful  resource controller. This way you're always sure that the parameters are delivered as you expect them. BTW you're welcome ;)